# find specific number from column a and sum up values greater than

Tags: excel

I google but could not succeed. Need excel formula. There are 3 columns data. In first column having numbers multiple of 50, say 5150,5200,5250 and so on. In column second and third have sells values. Daily I get one figure or number which is at say in column F1. This number could be anything between the range in column first, say the number could be 5455 or 6177 anything. Now I want to find and match the above number in first column and sum up all the values less than this number ( which is at F1) from column second and sum up values greater than this number from third column. The all three column data are from row 3 to row 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two SUMIF()

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"<=" & $F$1,B:B) + SUMIF(A:A,"<=" & $F$1,C:C)
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. Working fine. Made some changes. Taken output in two different columns for less than and greater than.